# Connecting to an Azure Webjob from an application within the same App Service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-webjobs, orleans

I've been using the Microsoft Orleans framework within my application, and am now trying to deploy it to Azure.  If you're not familiar, Orleans is a Virtual Actor framework that exposes servers called Silos where code is instantiated, held in memory until it's been idle for a set amount of time, and then unloaded.  My WebApi application then acts as a client and will connect to the Orleans silos.

I have deployed the WebApi application in an Azure App Service, and within that same App Service have created a continuous webjob that runs the Silo.  However, when the WebApi client tries to connect to the Silo, I'm seeing "Unable to connect" errors in the log (trying via TCP).

That made me think that maybe I needed to attach a Virtual Network to the Application Service, but that did not fix the issue (same log message) and I don't see anything that indicates that I would need to also add the webjobs to the Virtual Network.

Should I be able to connect these two applications together via the network?

Comment: Did you try using Azure Service fabric to host your Orleans application?

Comment: @baskar I have not.  I'll take a look at that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main site runs in a different sandbox from the WebJobs, which run in the 'scm site'. They're set up so that the scm site can talk to the Main site, but not vice versa. This may be what's blocking you here.

Try setting `WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION=true` if your Azure App Settings to make them run in the same sandbox (see [doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#use-the-same-process-for-the-user-site-and-the-scm-site)). Though note that technically it is no longer an officially supported mode. Still, it would be interesting to test whether that helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Do you know if there is a better way to do this going forward (since it's no longer technically supported)?

Comment: Not very familiar with Orleans, but maybe the WebAPI itself could launch the Silo processes itself (when it starts), which would later let it talk to them. Maybe not ideal, and others may have other ideas.